# Text Image Combined Classification Model

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network

I am working on a problem statement where I have to match (text, image) pair. Given a furniture description and furniture image, I have to say they are same or not. This is a binary classification problem but I have to combine both text and image data. 
One possible solution I am trying as follows
 [image]
In the above diagram, I am combining the feature from the pre-trained text and image model and training the linear layer end to end.

Is there any other way to handle this type of problem. any leads are most welcome. thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, an RNN with a Convnet attached is usually the way this is done, so looks like you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I got a few recent works for the problem of **"Image-Text Matching"** which is slightly different from my problem statement but I can adjust the code for my project.

1. Transformer Reasoning Network for Image-Text Matching and Retrieval [enter link description here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.09144v1.pdf)
2. Stacked Cross Attention for Image-Text Matching [enter link description here](https://kuanghuei.github.io/SCANProject/)